# Audit questions in Low Quality Posts have a Close button instead of a Delete button

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, low-quality-posts

I have sufficient reputation to delete questions, so for me, Low Quality Posts reviews on Stack Overflow display with a Delete button instead of a Close button.

However, I just saw an audit question where the Delete button was replaced with a Close button. This is a dead giveaway that the question is just an audit.

Answer (score 7):

This is a particular oddity with Stack Overflow's Low Quality Posts queue. On all other sites, both low quality questions and answers go to the Low Quality Posts queue. On Stack Overflow, **low quality questions instead go to the Triage queue**, so the Low Quality Posts queue only consists of answers... except for audits.

On any other site, the audit would not quite be so obvious. But on Stack Overflow, where the queue only shows  answers, an audit in the form of a question is blindingly obvious. In any case, this has been acknowledged as an issue on Meta Stack Overflow for several years now; see [Why does LQP still have question audits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289627/why-does-lqp-still-have-question-audits)

Answer (score 3):

There is no bug. It is working as intended.

The Close button appears in the review queue when the system identifies a question as low quality through its quality check or some user flags question as Very Low Quality. It is intended. Normal users can't delete a question through Very Low Quality Queue. They can only vote to close them. It puts the question 'On hold' and when the question is 'Closed', they can vote to delete.

Comment: As I stated in the question, I have high reputation (on Stackoverflow) so I can normally click Delete. For 99% of questions in that queue, I see a Delete button.

Comment: i too have a reputation on other site where I review low quality questions and vote to delete.  It shows "Close" instead of delete. It shows delete only for answers.

Comment: @RobinGreen It's not possible to delete a *question* from the LQP queue. We don't ever send already-closed questions there (except for audits).